# Authenticating WCF Service from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web application which will access a WCF Service hosted in the same IIS where the ASP.NET site will be hosted to communicate with the data layer.

ASP.NET site works on forms authentication by authenticating the user against user name and password stored in the sql database.

Since WCF Service is hosted on the internet, I want to prevent unauthorized access to the WCF Service i.e. only the users who are successfully authenticated by the ASP.NET site should be allowed to access the WCF service.

if an unauthorized user accesses the WCF service directly like http://test.com/service/userservice.svc or try to add service reference, it should throw exception.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In production you may want to turn off metadata exchange completely (unless your aspnet code is generating proxies on the fly which I don't think it will).

You can turn off metadata exposure by the following settings in web.cong/app.config in your service-
1. 
2. Remove metadata endpoint

Coming back to your second question-
It depends on what binding you are using in your WCF service. If you are not exposing or intend to expose your service to the outside world then net TCP binding is preferred usually because of its performance(You can host tcp based service in IIS 7+).

Considering it is a TCP based service, your endpoint wont be exposed on port 80 any ways so your service cannot be called by any clients directly (presuming your company's firewall only allows port 80 on that ip). You can further tighten up the security of your service by adding windows authentication to it.

I ve made some assumptions here so feel free to revert on this.

HTH

Comment: I would like to give some more inputs - ASP.NET Web site and WCF Service are hosted separately in the same IIS. SSL Certificate has been installed in the server so the communication will be through HTTPS. ASP.NET web site works on forms authentication. Since the WCF service is hsoted in the IIS and is available in the internet, we want to prevent unauthorized user from using the service. So, how can we prevent this? We want only the user who was authenticated by ASP.NET web site to access the WCF service.